# Changing a library symbol at runtime

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a problem and I'm not really sure where to start. What I have is an animation of a character in the library. The Character is made up of a few movieclips for the body that move about and one for the face that holds a stock photo. 
I have a camera section that grabs an image of the users face and now what I need to do is swap the stock face photo for the one taken in the last scene. No idea at all how to start on this, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you could do is make a movieclip of the stockphoto and then you could do the following:

head.removeChild(stockphoto_movieclip);
head.addChild(camera_image);

to take an image from the camera, there are plenty of tutorials online. It basically revolves around grabbing the bitmpdata of the camerastream.

Here's one [tutorial](http://www.tomontheweb2.ca/SloMo/index.cfm) that does just that...